# using jquery/javascript to get node text

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am doing this:

```
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                var checkText = $(this).next('a').text();
```

to get the node text of one of the nodes in my treeview

here is the HTML source:

```
<a class="TreeView1_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('TreeView1','sPreAnalytical\\Labels\\GoodStuff')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(TreeView1_Data, this,'TreeView1t2');" id="TreeView1t2">Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice</a>
```

the jquery line above returns:

```
Specimen collection device mislabeled/unlabeled by practice
```

however i need to return:

```
GoodStuff
```

how do i do it?

please note that i do not always have `\\Labels\\` in the text

what DOES stay constant is this: `href="javascript:__doPostBack('`

if it's much simpler i am even happy returning this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('TreeView1','sPreAnalytical\\Labels\\GoodStuff')
```

Comment: Quit those dirty hacks with your `javascript:` and inline event handlers.

Comment: @Raynos is this your email? raynos2@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the code below or something similar?

```
    var hrefValue = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
    var trimIndex = hrefValue.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    var checkText =  hrefValue.substr(trimIndex, hrefValue.length - 2);
```

Comment: the actual answer is this: var hrefValue = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
                var trimIndex = hrefValue.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
                var checkValue =  hrefValue.substr(trimIndex, hrefValue.indexOf("')",trimIndex)-trimIndex);   but yours def got me on the right path

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and parse the result.

```
$(this).next('a').attr('href')
```

Here's an example of parsing it with a regex.  The example has no error-checking so you'll probably want to improve it:

```
/([^\\']+)'\)$/.exec($(this).next('a').attr('href'))[1]
```